# R - datatable formatting with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, r

I'm trying to format datatable in R using DT package.
I have code like this:

```
library(data.table)
library(DT)
data<-data.table(rbind(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6)))
colnames(data)<- c('A','B','c')

datatable(data, rownames=F, 
      colnames=c('A','B','C'),
      class='stripe cell-border hover', 
      options=list(
        pageLength=100, 
        dom='ltp', 
        initComplete = JS("
                          function(settings, json) {
                          $(this.api().table().body()).css({
                          'background-color': 'red',
                          'outline-color': 'red',
                          'margin':'100px',
                          'color': 'violet',
                          'text-align': 'center',
                          'font-family': 'Courier New',
                          'border-radius': '25px'
                          });
                          $(this.api().table().header()).css({
                          'background-color': '#000',
                          'color': '#fff',
                          'outline-color': 'red',
                          'margin':'100px',
                          'text-align': 'center',
                          'font-family': 'Courier New',
                          'border-radius': '25px'
                          });
                          }
                          ")
        ), 
      caption = htmltools::tags$caption(
        style = 'caption-side: top; text-align: center; color:black; 
        font-size:200% ;','Table'),
      filter=list(position = 'top')
      )
```

And I have problem with javascript in function JS(). It modifies background color (but only in header), font color and style. But commands to align text or round corners don't work.

Why does it work like that?
And how can I modify code to format this other things?

Comment: Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a [bug](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/476) but there's a workaround proposed by timelyportfolio [here](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/348) using the function `prependContent` from `htmlwidgets`.

```
library(data.table)
library(DT)
library(htmlwidgets) #Load htmlwidgets package

data<-data.table(rbind(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6)))
colnames(data)<- c('A','B','c')

id <- paste0("dt-",htmlwidgets:::createWidgetId()) #Create an id name
dt <- datatable(data, rownames=F, elementId = id,  #Assign id name to datatable
      colnames=c('A','B','C'),
      class='stripe cell-border hover', 
      options=list(
        pageLength=100, 
        dom='ltp', 
        initComplete = JS("
                          function(settings, json) {
                          $(this.api().table().body()).css({
                          'background-color': 'red',
                          'outline-color': 'red',
                          'margin':'100px',
                          'color': 'violet',
                          'text-align': 'center',
                          'font-family': 'Courier New',
                          'border-radius': '25px'
                          });
                          $(this.api().table().header()).css({
                          'background-color': '#000',
                          'color': '#fff',
                          'outline-color': 'red',
                          'margin':'100px',
                          'text-align': 'center',
                          'font-family': 'Courier New',
                          'border-radius': '25px'
                          });
                          }
                          ")
        ), 
      caption = htmltools::tags$caption(
        style = 'caption-side: top; text-align: center; color:black; 
        font-size:200% ;','Table'),
      filter=list(position = 'top')
      )
```

Then you run `htmlwidgets::prependContent`

```
prependContent(
  dt,
  tags$style(sprintf(
    '#%s .dt-right {
    text-align: center;
}',id)))
```

Final result:
[image]